# using php/curl to login to a site with csrf protection

Tags: php, curl, csrf

I am trying to login to a site, with my own credentials (not trying to hijack a session), that uses csrf protection. I have some code written in python that scans the page, extracts the csrf string and sends it along with the username and password to be able to gain access to the restricted pages. I have tried searching for something similar in php/curl but cannot find anything.

All the google searching so far has only led to me links on how to integrate csrf protection to your login page, but not how to login to a site that uses it.

If someone could point me in the right direction or some basic code to get me started that would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is a very good question, as you dont show much of your research.
But to get you going a sort of plan:

1. Get the page with the token (use curl and make sure to enable a cookiejar)
2. Extract the token (use explode or preg_?)
3. Post to the page with your credentials and the 'ripped' token with curl
4. done ?

When your code is ready and does not work, post another question and we are willing to help with all love :-)